# Intersection between a line and a wave

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is it possible to find the points of intersection between a line and a sine wave?  I would like a function to find the nth intersection, rather than just first intersection within the domain of the wavelength.  Also, this is trivial to do for a simple example (e.g y=sin(x)), what I am looking for is a solution that can also be applied to complex waveforms, including the product of two waves.  If this is not possible can you please provide an explantion or direct me to a proof.  I would also appreciate recommendations on books that provide more information on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Wit depends on if you're looking for theoretical or computational answers. Newton's method will calculate the roots pretty quickly, or more complicated root-finding techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the typical trigonometric identities, and you see that the product of two sinusoidals is again one. So you are lucky, the only case you have to wonder about is the "simple" case $y = A \sin (\omega x + \phi)$. If you mean a straight line line paralell to the $x$-line, i.e., $y = c$, the solutions are straightforward:
$$
\begin{align*}
c &= \sin (\omega x + \phi) \\
\omega x + \phi &= \arcsin c + 2 n \pi \text{ or } \frac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin c  + 2 n \pi
\end{align*}
$$
(might need to fudge those to get the $n$-th intersection).
If the line isn't just $y = \text{constant}$, your only bet is using some numerical method.

Comment: > Apply the typical trigonometric identities, and you see that the product of two sinusoidals is again one.

Can you please indicate which trig identity you are referring to.

Comment: See for example this list of [sum and difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) formulas for $\sin$ and $\cos$, and apply e.g. $\cos x = \sin (\pi / 2 - x)$